# i want to add tree view inside form view.how it is possible

Tags: python-2.7, view, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I know how to group by tree view on my action but when tree view is inside of form view I have no idea and can't find any examples or sulutions. Is it a possibility to do that?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible sorry :( but you can use a button in order to open a wizard with the tree view you want to show and group

Answer (score 1):

In form_view, if you have any one2many field you can tree_view in form_view.

```
<group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="responsible_id"/>
                    </group> 
                    <notebook>                               
                        <page string="Description">
                            <field name="description"/>
                        </page> 
                        <page string="Sessions">
                            <field name="session_ids">
                                <tree>
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                    <field name="instructor_id"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
```

Here, session_ids is one2many field.

Comment: It's ok but the problem is that I can't group by tree view in form view.